# Harissa powder to paste

Tags: spices, olive-oil, middle-eastern-cuisine

How much harissa powder would be equivalent to one teaspoonful of harissa paste?

I have tried to look it up online, but all I can find is "add water and oil to reach the desired result", e.g. [here](http://www.geniuskitchen.com/about/harissa-827). I don't use the paste very often, so I doubt I will eyeball it right, any quantitative guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just in Morocco and asked some of the owners selling the spice how to do it, the answer I got was:

- Add 100 grams of Harissa powder
- Add 1/2 cup water
- Add 1/2 cup of EVOO

I would add that I have not tested this yet, and 100 grams is a lot to be making at once.

Comment: I tried the recipe above. It’s basically equal parts powder, water and oil. So to make a tablespoon’s worth of paste - combine 1 tsp powder, 1 tsp water and 1 tsp oil. It works!

Answer (score 4):

Impossible to say. 
Just mix and match. 
When it becomes a paste, you're done.

There is no "The Harissa Paste Recipe" (although most share the main ingredients), so you'll just have to go by the description on the package. Without knowing what's actually inside the package, my first instinct would be to stick with oil, and stay away from water.

Only if the powder includes dehydrated ingredients (onions, for example), and the rest of the recipe does NOT include water or watery ingredients, I'd include water in the mix.